# Dynamic Rolling X months - Pivot filter multiple selections

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

Hello I've inherited a dashboard that uses a Microsoft Analysis Server data source.

To improve performance I'm wanting to have the user select a date range like
LastMonth
Last3Months
Last6Months

My thought was to insert 3 Option buttons and when the user selects the button VBA code will change the filter selection.

I recorded the action of selecting the months but need suggestions on how to proceed.

```
Sub SelectMonth()
'
' SelectMonth Macro
'

'
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pv_DateRange").PivotFields( _
    "[Date].[Month - Year].[Month - Year]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
    "[Date].[Month - Year].&[201711]", "[Date].[Month - Year].&[201712]", _
    "[Date].[Month - Year].&[201801]", "[Date].[Month - Year].&[201802]", _
    "[Date].[Month - Year].&[201803]", "[Date].[Month - Year].&[201804]", _
    "[Date].[Month - Year].&[201805]", "[Date].[Month - Year].&[201806]", _
    "[Date].[Month - Year].&[201807]", "[Date].[Month - Year].&[201808]", _
    "[Date].[Month - Year].&[201809]")
End Sub
```

1. In the above example I selected was selecting last 12 full months. I this situation Oct 2017 was not present in my data so the option to select Oct 2017 was not displayed. How can I check to see what is displayed? or ignore if I attempt to set a value that is not shown in the filter list.
2. What is a good way to calculate and set each month in my VBA filter selection?

Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 0):

**--NOT TESETD--**

**Assuming your filter selection is going to stay in the format of "yyyymm" or year and month concatenated together.**

**I do not have any OLAP pivot tables, but I have used date filtering is some other pivots in VBA, so I hope this works, but it is not tested.**

If you want to use 3 option buttons and only have last 1 month, last 3 months or last 6 months, you can insert those 3 buttons onto the spreadsheet as ActiveXObject Command Buttons.

In the VBA Project Explorer, navigate to those sheets where the buttons appear you'll see subroutines for CommandButton1_Click(), CommandButton2_Click() and CommandButton3_Click(). For the private subs place this code where the command buttons 
subs are:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
SelectMonth (1)
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
SelectMonth (3)
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
SelectMonth (6)
End Sub
```

Then for your recorded macro replace it with this:

```
    Sub SelectMonth(NumOfMonths As Integer)
'
' Select Month Macro
'
'
' Declares string variables for the last 6 months relative to today
Dim Past1Month, Past2Month, Past3Month, Past4Month, Past5Month, Past6Month As String
Past1Month = Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "yyyymm")
Past2Month = Format(DateAdd("m", -2, Date), "yyyymm")
Past3Month = Format(DateAdd("m", -3, Date), "yyyymm")
Past4Month = Format(DateAdd("m", -4, Date), "yyyymm")
Past5Month = Format(DateAdd("m", -5, Date), "yyyymm")
Past6Month = Format(DateAdd("m", -6, Date), "yyyymm")

'determines which button is pressed and filters pivot to desired selection
If NumOfMonths = 1 Then
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pv_DateRange").PivotFields( _
        "[Date].[Month - Year].[Month - Year]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
        "[Date].[Month - Year].&[" & Past1Month & "]")
ElseIf numofmonth = 3 Then
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pv_DateRange").PivotFields( _
        "[Date].[Month - Year].[Month - Year]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
        "[Date].[Month - Year].&[" & Past1Month & "]", _
        "[Date].[Month - Year].&[" & Past2Month & "]", _
        "[Date].[Month - Year].&[" & Past3Month & "]")
ElseIf numofmonth = 6 Then
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pv_DateRange").PivotFields( _
        "[Date].[Month - Year].[Month - Year]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
        "[Date].[Month - Year].&[" & Past1Month & "]", _
        "[Date].[Month - Year].&[" & Past2Month & "]", _
        "[Date].[Month - Year].&[" & Past3Month & "]", _
        "[Date].[Month - Year].&[" & Past4Month & "]", _
        "[Date].[Month - Year].&[" & Past5Month & "]", _
        "[Date].[Month - Year].&[" & Past6Month & "]")
End If

End Sub
```

The other option is a dynamic selection, so the user can enter any number of months. You'll just need 1 command button and its code is:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

Dim x As Variant
x = InputBox("Enter Desired Number of Months to View", "Last X Months", 1)

If Not IsNumeric(x) Or x < 1 Then
    MsgBox "Please enter a valid positive number.", vbCritical, "ERROR"
    Exit Sub
End If

x = CInt(x)

SelectMonthDynamic (x)
End Sub
```

Then in the module place this code:

```
    Sub SelectMonthDynamic(NumOfMonths As Integer)
'
' User can enter any month
'
Dim DateArray() As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim PastXMonths As String

'creates an array that is the same size as your user's selection in months
ReDim DateArray(1 To NumOfMonths) As Variant

'adds each month to the array in descending order
For i = NumOfMonths To 1 Step -1
    DateArray(i) = "[Date].[Month - Year].&[" & Format(DateAdd("m", -i, Date), "yyyymm") & "]"
Next i

'concatenates the values in the array with a comma separator
PastXMonths = Join(DateArray, ",")

'filters the pivot to that selection
'   NOT SURE IF THIS WORKS
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pv_DateRange").PivotFields( _
    "[Date].[Month - Year].[Month - Year]").VisibleItemsList = Array(PastXMonths)

End Sub
```